# Can "Monit" monitor the processes running on remote servers?

Tags: nginx, monit

I want to setup `monit` on a server which is going to be a `centralized server` to monitor processes running on `remote servers`. I checked many docs related to setup monit but could not find how to setup for remote server processes. For example a `centralized monit server` should monitor `nginx` running on `A server`, `mongod` running on `B server` and so on. Any suggestion how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, Monit can be able to test the connection remotely, using tcp or udp, what you can do is to provide a small status file that gets refreshed for each technology you are intending to monitor, and let Monit hit that status file through http, etc. and can be used as follows:

```
check host nginxserver with address www.nginxserver.com
   if failed port 80 protocol http
      and request "/some_file"
   then alert
```

Since you are testing a web server that can be easily accomplished with the above. as a note , below is the part about Monit connection testing:

> CONNECTION TESTING Monit is able to perform connection testing via
>   networked ports or via Unix sockets. A connection test may only be
>   used within a check process or within a check host service entry in
>   the Monit control file.
>
> If a service listens on one or more sockets, Monit can connect to the
>   port (using either tcp or udp) and verify that the service will accept
>   a connection and that it is possible to write and read from the
>   socket. If a connection is not accepted or if there is a problem with
>   socket i/o, Monit will assume that something is wrong and execute a
>   specified action. If Monit is compiled with openssl, then ssl based
>   network services can also be tested.
>
> The full syntax for the statement used for connection testing is as
>   follows (keywords are in capital and optional statements in
>   [brackets]),
>
> IF FAILED [host] port [type] [protocol|{send/expect}+] [timeout]
>   [retry] [[]  CYCLES] THEN action [ELSE IF SUCCEEDED [[] 
>   CYCLES] THEN action]
>
> or for Unix sockets,
>
> IF FAILED [unixsocket] [type] [protocol|{send/expect}+] [timeout]
>   [retry] [[]  CYCLES] THEN action [ELSE IF SUCCEEDED [[] 
>   CYCLES] THEN action]
>
> host:HOST hostname. Optionally specify the host to connect to.  If the
>   host is not given then localhost is assumed if this test is used
>   inside a process entry. If this test was used inside a remote host
>   entry then the entry's remote host is assumed.  Although host is
>   intended for testing name based virtual host in a HTTP server running
>   on local or remote host, it does allow the connection statement to be
>   used to test a server running on another machine. This may be useful;
>   For instance if you use Apache httpd as a front-end and an
>   application-server as the back-end running on another machine, this
>   statement may be used to test that the back-end server is running and
>   if not raise an alert.
>
> port:PORT number. The port number to connect to
>
> unixsocket:UNIXSOCKET PATH. Specifies the path to a Unix socket.
>   Servers based on Unix sockets always run on the local machine and do
>   not use a port.